# OrientDB SQL function parameter values are not accessible inside the function body

Tags: sql, function, orientdb

I tried to write a SQL function in OrientDB to do inserts on a table `Feature`. The function body looks like this and it accepts two parameters `w` and `t`.

`insert into Feature (weight, title) values (w, t) return @rid`

When I execute this function with the parameters specified as `12` and `some title` the response I get is this.

`[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#21:24135",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "Feature",
        "weight": null,
        "title": null
    }
]`

It looks as if the parameters have not been set, hence the values `12` and `some title` have no visibility within the function. I also tried using `$` like special characters preceding the parameter name in the function body (refering to the parameter values as `$t` insteaed of `t`) and still didn't get lucky.

Comment: Hi Raajerc, could you post the whole function and how did you declare `wieght ` and `title`?

Comment: Hi LucaS, this is the complete function. I didn't declare any variable specifically. Do we have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query

```
insert into Feature (weight, title) values (:w, :t) return @rid
```

Comment: Worked the charm. But unfortunately, I already gave up and did the additions manually. Only saw this answer after I added all the data.

Answer (score 0):

can you see: "titile": null not "title", so with this insert into Feature (weight, **title**) values (w, t) return @rid, it couldnt find out the properties to assign, I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you executed the command

`insert into Feature (weight, title) values (w, t) return @rid`

but you forgot to insert the quotes when you pass the parameters w and t.
Try this code:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var ins = g.command('sql','insert into Feature (weight, title) values ('+w+', "'+t+'")');
return ins;
```

**Output**:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#12:-2",
        "@version": 0,
        "@class": "Feature",
        "weight": 14,
        "title": "sometitle",
        "@fieldTypes": "weight=d"
    }
]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried running it on the browser itself and after seeing this answer, I tried including the passed parameters within quotes as well. But still I am not getting any values on fields `weight` or `title`

Comment: I have posted a screenshot [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u5v1uo&s=9#.VrIdinV94l8)